# Why do I get "Nothing to compile" everytime I run forge test -m *testname* on my foundry project?

Tags: testing, foundry, forge

I always get "Nothing to compile" everytime I run forge test -m *testname* on my foundry project and I don't know why

Comment: Please add as much context as you can. For example, add your test file and forge version in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind everyone, I wasn't in the correct directory